# Checking if time is between two times in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building an application in Node.js, I'm noob at Javascript.

So, I'm trying to build validations for my application, I created a mysql database table to insert events, and these events can't run at the same time.

Thats my table:

```
replay_id
replay_hour_begin (varchar) (00:00:00)
replat_hour_end (varchar) (00:00:00)
```

The inserted hour is being received through parameters, and I'm checking if there is any event on database that will occur at the same time.

And that's the function that I built to validate the users input:

```
function checkEvent(hour, callback){

  connection.query('Select * from replay', function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) callback(err, null)
    else 

        var startTime = rows[0].replay_hour_begin;
        var endTime = rows[0].replay_hour_end;
        var insertedTime = hour;

        var getStartTime = new Date(); 
        var getEndTime = new Date();
        var getInsertedTime = new Date();

        getStartTime.setHours(startTime.split(":")[0]);
        getStartTime.setMinutes(startTime.split(":")[1]);

        getEndTime.setHours(endTime.split(":")[0]);
        getEndTime.setMinutes(endTime.split(":")[1]);

        getInsertedTime.setHours(insertedTime.split(":")[0]);
        getInsertedTime.setMinutes(insertedTime.split(":")[1]);

        console.log(getStartTime.getTime());
        console.log(getEndTime.getTime());
        console.log(getInsertedTime.getTime());

        var valid = getStartTime.getTime() < getInsertedTime.getTime() && getEndTime.getTime() > getInsertedTime.getTime();

        console.log(valid);

        //callback(null,true);


  });
}
```

The variable check is checking if the inserted hour is occupied.

But I always receive "false", even when I send a valid value.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind an extra library you can try [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) using moment [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) method.

```
moment('2010-10-20').isBetween('2010-10-19', '2010-10-25');
```

Now you said you have a database and you are querying the WHOLE database and checking, this is inefficient. Databases optimize queries and checks for you. You should let MySQL handle it for you, for example here:

```
SELECT * FROM `replay` WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2016-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2016-09-29 10:15:55')
```

Do not load the entire database and check it on the app.

Now just for the sake of the question to check if one date is between other two you can simply compare the dates.

```
var a = new Date(SOME_DATE)
var b = new Date(OTHER_DATE)
var c = new Date(DATE_TO_CHECK)

var isBetween = c>=a && c<=b || c>=b && c<=a
```